# How can I dim all foreground colors in TMUX without custom theming for active/inactive windows?

Tags: macos, vim, tmux

## Context

I'm using TMUX + VIM, and using a slightly customized gruvbox theme for both of them. In my `~/.tmux.conf`, I have tried adding the following lines:

```
set -sa terminal-overrides ",*:dim=\\033[2m"
set -g window-style 'fg=[default,dim],bg=default'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=default,bg=default'
```

I'm also currently using `https://github.com/TaDaa/vimade` for dimming vim panes when they're inactive (and it works with TMUX pane toggling in/out of VIM as well)

## Problem

My TMUX panes don't dim when I move away from them. Am I misunderstanding how `fg=[default,dim]` should work? I'd expect it to automatically apple `dim` when I move away from my panes.

## More context:

```
$ tmux showmsgs -T | grep dim
25: dim: (string) \033[2m
```

`echo -e '\033[2matest'` prints out `atest`, and it is correctly dimmed.

I'm using alacritty on MacOS (both latest versions) with Tmux verison `2.9a`